# Which (approximative) methods are there to compute the inverse of a complicated function?

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, power-series, approximation, inverse

I have a complicated function $f(x)$ for which I want to compute the inverse $f^{-1}$ over a certain range $R(f): a \leq f(x) \leq b$.

1. The only way to find the inverse I can think of is power series reversion at multiple points within the interval $(a,b)$, so that the radii of convergence of the inverse series overlap. One can try to improve the fit by using Newton's method on $f(y)-x = 0$.
2. Lagrange's theorem offers another method (see [[Dominici]](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501052)).
3. [[Dominici]](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501052) gives a third using nested derivatives.
4. Using Newton's method on the equation $f(y)-x = 0$ is probably the first choice. It gives the values of the inverse function at discrete points $x_i$. See [StackExchange (thanks Antonio Vargas)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800476/equations-solved-with-newtons-method-by-finding-the-zeros-of-functions/803185#803185) and [[Koepf]](http://www.mathematik.uni-kassel.de/~koepf/Publikationen/Koepf1994.pdf)

Are there other methods to compute the inverse of a complicated function $f$?

Comment: You could try to approximate $f$ by an analytically invertible function then use Newton's method to correct the approximation as in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/871516/5531).

Comment: Is there a method to choose such a function from a certain class of functions?

Comment: Not in general.

Comment: Is the function monotone? (Otherwise the inverse isn't defined). Also, if you are looking for a numerical approximation, then I don't understand what "choose from a certain class of functions" means.

Comment: Of course, the function is strictly monotone.

Comment: What do you mean by "compute" $f^{-1}$?  If you want to solve $f(x) = y$ for $x$, given $y$, there are numerical methods for that.

Comment: I would like to have a power series representation for taking derivatives and integrating. How would you go about numerically computing $f^{-1}$ for a known function $f(x)$?

Comment: [This answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800476/equations-solved-with-newtons-method-by-finding-the-zeros-of-functions/803185#803185) may give you an idea of how one could numerically compute an inverse.